# Excel 2016 VBA says "ambiguous name" but function declaration unique (was working before upgrade)

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I've got a VBA macro in an Excel 2016 workbook (Windows 10) which has existed and worked for years (it was written when I was still using Office 2010). I've since upgraded to Office 2016, but now the macro fails with the error: "Ambiguous name detected: bIgnore". This is the failing line of code

```
If Not bIgnore(strDesc) Then
```

The bIgnore function is declared only once across all of my modules, and looks like this:

```
Function bIgnore(pDesc As String)
    'If the description is in the "Ignore List" sheet then return True
    Dim nRow As Integer

    Set wIgnore = Worksheets("Ignore List")

    nRow = 1
    While wIgnore.Range("A" & nRow).Value <> ""
        If InStr(1, pDesc, wIgnore.Range("A" & nRow).Value) > 0 Then
            bIgnore = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        nRow = nRow + 1
    Wend

    bIgnore = False

 End Function
```

Any idea why it is now being regarded as ambiguous by the compiler?

Comment: You need to drop [Systems Hungarian](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) notation. There's *something else*, *somewhere*, by that name, and it's in public scope. BTW your function should be declared `As Boolean` - question: if the function's signature says `As Boolean`, and call sites see `As Boolean` in IntelliSense, why would you need that `b` prefix for?

Comment: I've searched the whole project - there are 6 references to bIgnore in total - all coded identically to the first code sample above ("if not bIgnore(..."). The only other instances of that string are in the function declaration itself. The fact that this worked fine until I upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 2016 suggests that there isn't a fundamental problem with the function declaration. The b prefix is just an "old habits die hard" issue!

Comment: VBA itself had no update between Office 2010 and Office 2016, so I doubt the Office upgrade had anything to do with it. FWIW I still think [this would be worth a shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DmB4.png). That error would occur if you declared a `bIgnore` variable somewhere. Keep searching with the VBE's terrible search feature, or use *Find Symbol* to find it in 2 seconds.

Comment: What's the code surrounding that line of code? Is the function declared in a standard module?

Comment: Ok I installed RubberDuck, hit Ctrl-T and entered bIgnore as the search string. It did nothing. The blue arrow next to the search argument box didn't seem to respond to clicks, and hitting Enter didn't do anything either.

Comment: I also just did a global search/replace of bIgnore with bIIgnore and get the same error for bIIgnore. The line of code immediately preceding the function call varies in each case, but the first time it's called this is the previous line: "For nIdx = 2 To nLastRow
    strDesc = wSheet.Range("B" & nIdx).Value"

Comment: Yes the bIgnore function is defined in a module. Not quite sure what you mean by "standard module" though?

Comment: Is `Option Explicit` specified?

Comment: Hmmm....I just tried the previous version of Rubberduck (v2.1.0.2338-pre) and got exactly the same problem.

Comment: Yeah I made a comment on the linked issue - the bug was accidentally introduced with .2336; I'm using .2334 at work with no such issues.

Answer (score 0):

An ambiguous name is a compile error that always means VBA is seeing *at least* two identifiers with the same name, in the same scope.

Normally the compile error should just take you there, and highlight the problematic declaration.

Other than that, you can use the VBE's search (Ctrl+F) functionality and try to locate the faulty declaration, but the tool is rather basic/weak, and won't list all results - it *iterates* them instead... which can be painful.

Alternatively you could try to use [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s *Find Symbol* (Ctrl+T) command (assuming the code can be parsed... Rubberduck mostly assumes the code is compilable in the first place), and see every declaration by that name - and that's if the *Code Explorer* (Ctrl+R) doesn't already reveal the problem:

[image: Rubberduck's 'Code Explorer' and 'Find Symbol' tools showing the duplicate declarations]

**Disclaimer:** I'm heavily involved with the development of the Rubberduck VBIDE add-in.

---

Another alternative, since Rubberduck uses a *symbol table* and scoping rules to resolve identifier references, would be to *refactor/rename* (Ctrl+Shift+R) the function to, say, `IsIgnored`, and then use *Find Symbol* again to locate the `bIgnore` declaration that remained: that should be your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try replacing all instances of "bIgnore" with "blIgnore" and see if it still conflicts or not.

If the error goes away then surely it is keyword conflict.